# Rails turn form to bootstrap form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the time i have defined two search forms in my app:[image]

How you can see the second form doesnt look so nice and disturbs my layout.
So my aim is to style the working form (second form) like the first form.

But i have my problems to define the html in the rails form:

First form:

```
 <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
   <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Suche">
 </form>
```

Second Form:

```
<%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why aren't you styling the second form the same way as the first? Look at how bootstrap describes the way to style search forms: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first start would be:

```
<%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get', {class: ["navbar-search", "pull-left"]} do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search-query" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get a syntax error trying to add class like that `{class: ["navbar-search", "pull-left"]}`